# How print Body sent from proxy to client php?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, response, httpresponse

I use a php proxy through which I can make **POST** requests via `CURL` to the servers of a website.

```
$response = curl_exec($request);
```

if i `print_r($response)` i have a big output...Headers sent to proxy Host, Headers sent to target POST and Body sent from proxy to client but i want to print only **Body sent from proxy to client**.

How can i do this ?

Body sent is like:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Lana","loc":[{"line":1,"column":1}],"path":["bufield"],"extensions":{"code":30056,"type":"FOR"}}],"data":{"bufield":null}}
```

i would to **print** only content of `data`

Comment: Explain your question properly.

Comment: @SaifAliKhan please read better "if i print_r($response) i have a big output...Headers sent to proxy Host, Headers sent to target POST and Body sent from proxy to client but i want to print only Body sent from proxy to client."

Comment: Just repeating what you already said, does not add any clarification, and prefixing it with an arrogant statement such as "please read better" doesn't change that either.

Comment: [From comments under existing answer] _"LOL.... obviously this is not the answer ... thank you but there is already that line of code"_ - how should we know, what lines of code already exist on your end, if you don't show us? Instead of giving the people trying to help you lip, provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```php
$response = curl_exec($request);

print_r(json_decode($response, true)["data"]);

// It should give you the following:
// {"bufield":null}
```

Comment: LOL.... obviously this is not the answer ... thank you but there is already that line of code

Comment: Do you want to access data property? Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes... i want to print only content of "data"